# In Firefox Private browsing window, how does the content script of an addon set cookie

Tags: firefox-addon, session-cookies, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to build an addon that allows super users of a website to login as a regular user within a private browsing window. So when a super user clicks a button, a private browsing window would popup and I'm trying to set the correct cookies to login the super user as a regular user. The problem I'm having now is that document.cookie = '...' does not seem to work within private browsing windows. Is there a way to solve this problem?

P.S. If the popup window is a regular window, then the super user could be logged in as a regular user, and I can see that my code works. But then the problem is that the session of the original window would break.

Comment: not sure what you want to do...a private window is a brand new session, there is no way to know if that person was a superuser in different session

Comment: @RedAlert couldn't we just check all sessions and access/see what's going on over there?